# How to put an image in a specific JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, grid-layout

I am experimenting with board games lately and now I am making a *Checkers* board game. However I cannon figure out how to display a chip in a cell of the `GridLayout`. Each cell has it's own ***JPanel*** that I assigned in a 2D Array by a ***FOR Loop***.

I need to display the image `p1Chip` which is just a `.png` in a specific ***JPanel***, lets say it's variable name name is `board[2][3]`, without messing up the `GridLayout`.

A sample code on how I can do this would be great as it will help me out understand better.

I have searched the internet but I can't find what I need, or at least something that explains how to do it.

Here is the code so far:

```
package checkers;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Image;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.ImageObserver;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Main extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;

    Image p1Chip;

    JPanel[][] board = new JPanel[8][8];



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Main frame = new Main();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public Main() throws IOException {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 800, 800);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        startGame();
    }


    //Start Game!
        public void startGame() throws IOException{
            drawBoard();
        }

//******************************DRAWS BOARD******************************\\

 //Draws the board
    public void drawBoard() throws IOException{

        System.out.println("Start Drawing Board!");

        getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout(8,8));

        int colorAssignRow = 0; 
        int colorAssignCol = 0;

        for(int r = 0; r < 8; r++){

            colorAssignRow++;
            colorAssignCol = 0;

            for(int c = 0; c < 8; c++){

                colorAssignCol++;

                board[r][c] = new JPanel();


                if(colorAssignRow%2!=0){
                    if(colorAssignCol%2==0)board[r][c].setBackground(Color.RED);
                        else board[r][c].setBackground(Color.BLACK);
                }
                else if(colorAssignRow%2==0){
                    if(colorAssignCol%2==0)board[r][c].setBackground(Color.BLACK);
                    else board[r][c].setBackground(Color.RED);
                }

                getContentPane().add(board[r][c]);
            }

        }

        System.out.println("Board Drawing Done!");


    }

//******************************END OF DRAWING BOARD******************************\\

    public void getAssets(){
        System.out.println("Getting assets!");
        p1Chip = new ImageIcon("P1ChipNormal.png").getImage();
    }

}
```

The code above works fine as it just outputs the Checkers board of ***JPanels***, each in a different cell of the grid.

UPDATE:
This method is added to display the chips, however when I run this method, no chips show up.

```
 public void drawChips(){


    /*
     * When:    0 and even
     *          1 and odd
     *          2 and even
     */

    //Drawing Player One Chips\\
    for(int r = 0; r < 8; r++){ 
        for(int c = 0; c < 8; c++){

            label[r][c] = new JLabel();
            board[r][c] = new JPanel();

            if(r==0 && c%2==0){
                label[r][c].setIcon(p1Chip);
                board[r][c].add(label[r][c]);
            }
            else if(r==1 && c%2!=0 && c!=0){
                label[r][c].setIcon(p1Chip);
                board[r][c].add(label[r][c]);
            }
            else if(r==2 && c%2==0){
                label[r][c].setIcon(p1Chip);
                board[r][c].add(label[r][c]);
            }

    }   
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To show a chip in a JPanel cell:

- Put the chip image into an ImageIcon
- Put that ImageIcon into a JLabel via JLabel's `setIcon(chipIcon)` method
- Add the JLabel to the JPanel via the `add(someLabel)` method -- and the JPanel now will display the image.

Then if you want to click and move the chip,

- give it MouseListener and MouseMotionListener (MouseAdapater)
- When clicked, remove the JLabel from its containing JPanel and elevate it to the top level window's glass pane.
- Move it with the MouseAdapter.
- When released, place the JLabel the JPanel that the mouse is over.

Comment: Much better than my solution =) +1

Comment: Yeah your solution worked great this time. Thanks a lot for your help Hovercraft and Little Child :) +1

Comment: @user2904544: you're welcome. If little child's advice helped, then you'll want to also up-vote his answer (as I have done).

Comment: I can't really upvote due to rep as I just started using StackOverflow recently.

Comment: If @LittleChild up-votes your question, then you'll have the required 15 rep points to allow you to upvote his answer.

Comment: I got a question, if I create another method to create the Chips for Player 1, all I need to do is `label[r][c] = new JLabel()` and `board[r][c]= new JPanel()` and then just create 2 for loops to display the chips? Because when I do it in another method, it is not working. I will update my code.

NOTE: When It worked I did this in the method `drawBoard()` and I want to do it in a separate method.

Answer (score 1):

1. Set the size, manually, of each of the `JPanel` in the board to be as large as the image plus some padding if you choose.
2. Maintain a 2d array containing your `JPanel`s.
3. Call `repaint()` on your `JPanels` whenever the user clicks on it. Do not forget to overrride the `paintComponent()` where you draw the image onto the `JPanel`

Here is how you might do the painting of image:

```
JPanel onePanel = new JPanel(){
                                @Override
                                public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
                                    super.paintComponent(g);
                                    g.drawImage(image,0,0,null);
                                }
                            }
```

In the snippet above, I have created a custom `JPanel` so as to suit the needs.

So, lets say the user clicks on the first `JPanel` which is on position (0 , 0). You retrieve the `JPanel` from the `board[][]` and call `repaint()` on it. This will result in the image being drawn.

Comment: This also worked for me, but needed a little bit of tweaking here and there. Thanks :)